# Single Event Bus for Multiple Event Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, design-patterns

I setup an event bus that simply passes a string for all event types. This worked well but now I want different event arguments for each event type. I don't see a way to keeping a single collection of subscribers that all have different event arguments. I can use a base type for the event arguments, but then the event handlers are forced to use the base type and the subscribers has to cast the event arguments to the concrete type (which I don't want). I basically have something like this:

```
public abstract class PresentationEvent

{
    private readonly List<Action<IPresentationEventArgs>> _subscribers = new List<Action<IPresentationEventArgs>>();

    public void Subscribe(Action<IPresentationEventArgs> action)
    {
        _subscribers.Add(action);
    }

    public void Publish(IPresentationEventArgs message)
    {
        foreach (var sub in _subscribers)
        {
            sub.Invoke(message);
        }
    }
}

 public class MessageChangedEvent : PresentationEvent
    {

    }

public static class EventBus 
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, PresentationEvent> _mapping = new Dictionary<Type, PresentationEvent>();

        private static PresentationEvent GetPresentationEvent<T>() where T : PresentationEvent, new()
        {
            if (_mapping.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            {
                return _mapping[typeof(T)];
            }

            var presEvent = new T();
            _mapping.Add(typeof(T), presEvent);

            return presEvent;
        }

        public static void Subscribe<T>(Action<IPresentationEventArgs> action) where T: PresentationEvent, new()
        {
            var presEvent = GetPresentationEvent<T>();
            presEvent.Subscribe(action);
        }

        public static void Publish<T>(IPresentationEventArgs args) where T : PresentationEvent, new()
        {
            var presEvent = GetPresentationEvent<T>();
            presEvent.Publish(args);
        }
    }
```

But when handling the event, I am forced to do this:

```
private void OnMessageChanged(IPresentationEventArgs x)
        {
// do cast here
        }
```

instead of:

```
 private void OnMessageChanged(MessageChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            label1.Text = args.Message;
        }
```

Other than keeping some event dictionary with different lists for each event type, I am not sure how I would handle this. I know there are third party libraries out there but I'd prefer to write the code myself. I've also looked at similar questions and don't find anything. If anyone has a suggestion on how to solve this problem or other recommendations it would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: I recently wrote (with a lot of help and snippets from the great engineers here) an event publisher which can handle any type of event, the source code is in a question i have posted about refactoring but it should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615382/refactoring-service-which-uses-reflection-to-build-methods-and-then-invoke-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add another generic parameter you can have strongly typed events.

```
public interface IPresentationEventArgs { }

public abstract class PresentationEvent<TPresentationEventArgs> where TPresentationEventArgs : IPresentationEventArgs
{
    private readonly List<Action<TPresentationEventArgs>> _subscribers = new List<Action<TPresentationEventArgs>>();

    public void Subscribe(Action<TPresentationEventArgs> action)
    {
        _subscribers.Add(action);
    }

    public void Publish(TPresentationEventArgs message)
    {
        foreach (var sub in _subscribers)
        {
            sub.Invoke(message);
        }
    }
}

public class MessageChangedEventArgs : IPresentationEventArgs 
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class MessageChangedEvent : PresentationEvent<MessageChangedEventArgs>
{

}

public static class EventBus
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<Object>> _mapping = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Object>>();

    private static T GetPresentationEvent<T, TArgs>()
        where T : PresentationEvent<TArgs>, new()
        where TArgs : IPresentationEventArgs
    {
        if (_mapping.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return _mapping[typeof(T)]() as T;
        }

        var presEvent = new T();
        _mapping.Add(typeof(T), () => presEvent);

        return presEvent;
    }

    public static void Subscribe<T, TArgs>(Action<TArgs> action) where T : PresentationEvent<TArgs>, new()
        where TArgs : IPresentationEventArgs
    {
        var presEvent = GetPresentationEvent<T, TArgs>();
        presEvent.Subscribe(action);
    }

    public static void Publish<T, TArgs>(TArgs args) where T : PresentationEvent<TArgs>, new()
        where TArgs : IPresentationEventArgs
    {
        var presEvent = GetPresentationEvent<T, TArgs>();
        presEvent.Publish(args);
    }
}
```

So a small test program to demonstrate how this could work:

```
class Program
{
    static void OnMessageChanged(MessageChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventBus.Subscribe<MessageChangedEvent, MessageChangedEventArgs>(OnMessageChanged);
        EventBus.Publish<MessageChangedEvent, MessageChangedEventArgs>(new MessageChangedEventArgs{ Message = "Hello world."});

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

You have the added overhead of calling subscribe and publish with 2 generic parameters, but on the other hand you can bind an event to specific eventArgs and consumers cannot pass any arbitrary eventArgs for a given event. They would need to match.

Here is a small optimisation. Rather than create your own list of actions, you could just add actions up and allow the power of a Multicast delegate to keep track of all the actions for you. For example:

```
public abstract class PresentationEvent<TPresentationEventArgs> where TPresentationEventArgs : IPresentationEventArgs
{
    private Action<TPresentationEventArgs> _actions = args => { };

    public void Subscribe(Action<TPresentationEventArgs> action)
    {
        _actions += action;
    }

    public void Publish(TPresentationEventArgs message)
    {
        _actions(message);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is one other way you can do the subscription. But no matter which approach you take, if you want statical linking and compile time checks then you will need to supply 2 type arguments.

- 1 type argument to specify the type of event you want to subscribe to.
- 1 type argument to cast the method being subscribed to as an Action since the compiler cannot infer it being the case just from the method signature

With that in mind here is another way, but you don't avoid having to specify 2 arguments.

```
public static class IPresentationEventArgsExtensions
{
    public static void SubscribeTo<TEvent, TArgs>(this TEvent target, Action<TArgs> action)
        where TArgs : IPresentationEventArgs
        where TEvent : PresentationEvent<TArgs>, new()
    {
        EventBus.Subscribe<TEvent, TArgs>(action);
    }
}

// Use
 Action<MessageChangedEventArgs> messageChangedMethod = OnMessageChanged; // The compiler cannot infer that OnMessageChanged is a Action<IPresentationEventArgs>
 new MessageChangedEvent().SubscribeTo(messageChangedMethod);
```

Comment: You are a genius. This is exactly what I needed. Inheriting from the presentation event and passing in the argument type is very clever.

Comment: I wish there was a way though to have this subscribe look at some type parameter of the message (maybe that's exposed as a property via the interface) that it could use to determine the type of the arguments rather than it having to be passed in?

Comment: Thank you again! You have been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do some interesting things with generic interfaces which cannot be done with delegates.  One approach that might be workable here, if each class which uses your "events" will only need to have one handler for each type of parameter, would be to define an interface `IKingEventHandler<T>` with method `InvokeEvent(T param)`, and have a method `RaiseKingEvent<TT>(TT param)` which searches through a list of subscribed handler objects and invokes any that implement `IKingEventHandler<TT>`.  If one doesn't want to define separate parameter types for every type of handler, one could include a dummy type parameter in addition to the parameter type.  This approach would somewhat limit the patterns of events that could be handled, but it would have a few advantages over normal delegates:

1. For better or for worse, putting an object into the subscriber list would automatically attach all of its associated events.

   The subscriber list could hold each subscriber as a `WeakReference`, thus avoiding the memory-leak problems that traditionally plague event publishers.

This is hardly the most interesting thing that interfaces can do that delegates cannot (the ability for interfaces to support open generic methods is far more interesting) but it may nonetheless be a useful pattern in some situations.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is akin to the first answer but without creating a class for each event type?

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites: Each event type would need to have its own defined class for purposes of identifying it and holding its associated parameters, but the event dispatch code would be common to all event types.

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar for raising domain events.  Here is the basic idea (changed the code so it is untested):

```
public static class EventBus
{
    private static List<Delegate> actions;

    public static void Register<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : IPresentationEvent
    {
        if (actions == null)
        {
            actions = new List<Delegate>();
        }

        actions.Add(callback);
    }

    public static void ClearCallbacks()
    {
        actions = null;
    }

    public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IPresentationEvent
    {
        if (actions == null)
        {
           return;
        }

        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            if (!(action is Action<T>))
            {
                continue;
            }

            ((Action<T>)action).Invoke(args);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**:

I have a marker interface:

```
public interface IPresentationEvent
{
}
```

And the handlers look like this:

```
public interface IHandlePresentationEvent<T> where T : IPresentationEvent
{
    void Handle(T args);
}
```

Comment: I like where you are going with this. I had tried something similar, but I see my problem is I needed to use a list of delegate inside of action<argbaseinterface> for my subscriber list. How would I prevent someone from publishing the wrong argument types with an event? I guess I'd want to find a good way to create a hard association between event types and event argument types. Also my subscribe becomes kinda ugly: EventBus.Subscribe<MessageChangedEvent, MessageChangedEventArgs>(x => OnMessageChanged(x));

Comment: Then there is also the question of how to handle events that has no arguments using the same methods (since no second type param would apply).

Comment: Or perhaps you are saying to get rid of the original event type and just use the event argument type to identify the event?

Comment: Since your event *is* the argument there is no possibility to send the wrong argument with the event.  You effectively have a handler looking something like `public void Handle(...event argument...)` --- updated answer

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but your code only deals with one type (the type of message). I have 2 different classes. One for the message (MessageChangedEvent) and one for the arguments (MessageChangedEventArgs). From looking at your code it looks like maybe you use the the arguments as the message class itself. When I try your code I have something like this:
EventBus2.Register<MessageChangedEvent>(x => OnMessageChanged2(x)); But now my event handler expects the event class as the argument when really it is the argument class that I want. I dont see a way without two types. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't define different 'event' handlers.  There is always only one and that takes the event containing all the data.  So if a class subscribes to multiple events it will implement `IHandlePresentationEvent` for each event type.  So you do not register your subscriber for a specific event.  You just register.  Since it only handles certain events it will only be called if it actually implements handling of that type of event. HTH

Comment: You say event handlers but I am talking about event classes. I have a class called MessageChangedEvent that represents a MessageChangedEvent. You are passing in a class that implements IPresentationEvent to the subscribe... In my case that would be the MessageChangedEvent class. I had intended to use a separate arguments class that actually gets published and then use the event class to run any generic code when the command gets published. I'm now leaning towards just using the message type class for arguments and not trying to run common code on an event fire. Prob same as ur doing. Thx again

Comment: Also btw... If you check out the first answer you can see where i was originally going. This will help clarify my last comment. In any case +1 and thank you.